# Header in android application with navigation menu

Tags: android

I am new to Android and I want to know how to best develop my app.

My app is going to be only on tablets and I have a navigation menu on the header (not side menu like a NavDrawer but a navigation menu on header like in websites).

The question is if it's better to make a header.xml file that contains all the navigation buttons and include it in every activity, and then in order to handle click events make it inside some base activity that every activity will inherit from.
Or it's better to make the header as a fragment and handle the click events inside the fragment itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Current practice is to use a Toolbar with either a navigation tab with a spinner or Tabs/Icons for each of your views. If you don't want to build this yourself you can use the TabbedActivity template when you set up your project.

The way it works is it's a Toolbar(new version of the ActionBar) included on the top of an Activity that has a fragment for the rest of the view. You can use a ViewPager or a FragmentManager to change the content of the fragment as the user makes his/her selection.

Here is the main activity of an app I built like this recently:

```
<RelativeLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#dfdfdf">

<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_below="@id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tabs"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the toolbar looks something like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```